# Replacing div with another on click

Tags: javascript

My knowledge of javascript is close to none and I'm trying to have a div be replaced on click by another div.

```html
<div class='replace-on-click'>
      <h1><a href="#">Click to Insert Coin</a></h1>
      <div class='replaced-with'>
        <div class='info-text'>
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <h2>Subtitles</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class='info-buttons'>
          <li><a href='#' class='b1'>Buy Tickets</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='b2'>Find Hotels</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I'd like it so when you click "Click to Insert Coin", that will disappear and make the `.replaced-with` div take its place, hopefully with some kind of fade transition if possible. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: use jquery show() and hide().  you can set the timing on those to look like they are animations http://api.jquery.com/show/                                                i would suggest adding a js file, select your h1 element and on click, hide it and show the other: `$(h1).on("click", function(){$(.replace-on-click).hide(); $(.replaced-with).show() });`  please realize the above is an example, and you should scope the selector more than using just `h1`

Comment: You can fetch elements with [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) -- you can add event listeners with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for the `click` event.  MDN is a good resource.  Your intent is to accomplish this with vanilla JavaScript (no libraries)?

Comment: My knowledge of JS isn't good enough to understand this right now. Also JS libraries are fine.

Answer (score 0):

We will make use of jQuery because it helps us to get you desired behavior done in a few statements. So first include jQuery from somewhere in your head part of your HTML document.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then somewhere include this Javascript code (e.g. create index.js and include it the way like the library code).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h1').click(function() {
       $(this).fadeOut(function() {
           $('.replaced-with').fadeIn();
       });
     });
});
```

It does the following: When your document is ready, it adds an event handler on h1 waiting for clicks. On click, it first fades out the h1 and when it's done, it fades the other element in.

In your HTML document, include the hidden attribute to the object that should be hidden initially.

```
      <div class='replaced-with' hidden>
```

Here you can find it working as well: http://jsbin.com/cuqoquyeli/edit?html,js,console,output